# css - width property

Tags: html, css, width

This is a follow-up question to one I asked before:

"CSS - elements position when the window size changes".

The issue was - How to avoid the elements from being pushed aside when the screen gets smaller.

The answer was - use static width.

Static width indeed solves the problem, however it causes another problem (now we get to my follow-up question):

Let's say I use a picture as a background for the headline of the site and another one for the footer.

On the one hand I want them to always take the whole screen width but on the other hand I don't want them to be pushed aside when the window displaying the site gets smaller.

Using static width will cause different display in different browsers or in different versions of the same browser - will not always take the whole width. (there isn't one static width value that is good for all cases)

Using width: `100%` seems to be the solution but then I find myself where I began.

How can I accomplish both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason that we have css media queries and max-width, max-height attributes

Media queries allow you to change the css depending on how big the screen size is. Plus they can do a lot more.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

What I would do is design your site with max-width: someamount,  and width: 100%. Once your finished, then worry about making it look better on smaller screens.

Designers usually go one of two ways when designing a responsive website. Either design for desktop size screen first, then adjust for the smaller sized screens towards the very end. OR design for mobile sized screens first and then the larger screens towards the very end.